# How to get the namespace from a controller in Rails7.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I plan to use namespaces to separate features of my application:

- namespace :administration will be accessible through /administration/ base URL
- namespace :governance will be accessible through /governance/ base URL
- etc.
- while other objects are accessible through the / base URL

When I was using Rails 5.2, I was retrieving the namespace from the controller:

```
  # Idenfify the namespace of the controller
  def namespace
    case controller.class.parent.name
    when 'Object'
      nil
    when 'Devise'
      :administration
    else
      controller.class.parent.name.downcase
    end
  end
```

I wish I could reuse my former code but now, with Rails 7.2, this raises an error:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `parent' for Devise::SessionsController:Class
```

I could not find a documentation or a good trick to replace this feature.
What is the best way now to find the namespace of a controller?

Comment: 7.2 or 7.0.7.2 ?

Comment: `Module#parent` is [removed in 6.1](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_1_release_notes.html#active-support-removals) version and [replaced in 6.0](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_0_release_notes.html#active-support-notable-changes) with `Module#module_parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parent` changed to `module_parent`

Edit: and there's also `module_parent_name` for the string.